# when trying to run celery local I get an error message

Tags: python, django, celery, file-structure

This is my file structure

```
venv/
 |-src/
   |-gettingstarted/
   |  |-settings/
   |     |-__init__.py
   |     |-base.py
   |     |-local.py
   |     |-production.py
   |
   |-blog/
   |  |-__init__.py
   |  |-admin.py
   |  |-forms.py
   |  |-models.py
   |  |-tasks.py
   |  |-urls.py
   |  |-views.py
   |
   |-manage.py
```

my views.py

```
from .tasks import add, p_panties

def shopan(request):
    # one = scrape_and_store_world()
    # two = panties()
    # argument_scrapes(one, two)
    p_panties.delay()
    return redirect('/')
```

my tasks.py

```
import requests
import random
import re
import os

from celery import Celery
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.task
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]


@app.task
def p_panties():
    def swappo():
        user_one = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0" '
        user_two = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)" '
        user_thr = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko" '
        user_for = ' "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0" '

        agent_list = [user_one, user_two, user_thr, user_for]
        a = random.choice(agent_list)
        return a

    headers = {
        "user-agent": swappo(),
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }

    pan_url = 'http://www.example.com'
    shtml = requests.get(pan_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(shtml.text, 'html5lib')
    video_row = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'post-start'})
    name = 'pan videos'

    

    def youtube_link(url):
        youtube_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soupdata = BeautifulSoup(youtube_page.text, 'html5lib')
        video_row = soupdata.find_all('p')[0]
        entries = [{'text': div,
                    } for div in video_row]
        tubby = str(entries[0]['text'])
        urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', tubby)
        cleaned_url = urls[0].replace('?&amp;autoplay=1', '')
        return cleaned_url

    def yt_id(code):
        the_id = code
        youtube_id = the_id.replace('https://www.example.com/embed/', '')
        return youtube_id

    def strip_hd(hd, move):
        str = hd
        new_hd = str.replace(move, '')
        return new_hd

    entries = [{'href': div.a.get('href'),
                'text': strip_hd(strip_hd(div.h2.text, '– Official video HD'), '– Oficial video HD').lstrip(),
                'embed': youtube_link(div.a.get('href')), #embed
                'comments': strip_hd(strip_hd(div.h2.text, '– Official video HD'), '– Oficial video HD').lstrip(),
                'src': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + yt_id(youtube_link(div.a.get('href'))) + '/maxresdefault.jpg', #image
                'name': name,
                'url': div.a.get('href'),
                # 'author': author,
                'video': True

                } for div in video_row][:13]
    
    return entries
```

in my terminal

```
(practice) apples-MBP:blog ray$ celery worker -A tasks -l info 
[2016-09-14 11:30:14,537: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/apps/worker.py:161: CDeprecationWarning: 
Starting from version 3.2 Celery will refuse to accept pickle by default.

The pickle serializer is a security concern as it may give attackers
the ability to execute any command.  It's important to secure
your broker from unauthorized access when using pickle, so we think
that enabling pickle should require a deliberate action and not be
the default choice.

If you depend on pickle then you should set a setting to disable this
warning and to be sure that everything will continue working
when you upgrade to Celery 3.2::

    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']

You must only enable the serializers that you will actually use.


  warnings.warn(CDeprecationWarning(W_PICKLE_DEPRECATED))
 
 -------------- celery@apples-MBP.fios-router.home v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x1037836a0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . tasks.add
  . tasks.p_panties
  . tasks.reverse

[2016-09-14 11:30:14,689: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2016-09-14 11:30:14,702: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2016-09-14 11:30:15,710: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2016-09-14 11:30:15,723: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@apples-MBP.fios-router.home ready.
```

when I try to run my my program this error message I get is

```
[2016-09-14 11:30:32,171: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'blog.tasks.p_panties'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see
```

[here](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-names) for more information.

```
The full contents of the message body was:
{'timelimit': (None, None), 'task': 'blog.tasks.p_panties', 'chord': None, 'taskset': None, 'errbacks': None, 'id': 'd9814eb1-98a9-4b45-b049-e36ac64fc55c', 'retries': 0, 'args': [], 'utc': True, 'expires': None, 'eta': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'callbacks': None} (263b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 456, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'blog.tasks.p_panties'
```

Am I supposed to make this an app so I can use it?

## EDIT

my blog/celery.py as you suggested me to write it

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gettingstarted.settings'
)

app = Celery('tasks')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

How I run the celery worker

```
celery worker -A tasks -l info
```

and I'm running it in the blog directory because that's where the tasks.py is, else If I run in src I get

```
No module named 'tasks'
```

but If I run it in src I get

```
Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Comment: **app = Celery('blog')** ! do not put tasks in there it's the name of the module.

So you do  app = Celery('blog'), and you run *celery worker -A blog -l info* in the src folder. see if this helps. If the problem persists, also update the tasks.py that you're using now in the post.

Comment: @SpiXel worked. In a tutorial I read, the first parameter of Celery() is named after the file it resides in. It was in tasks.py before so I had Celery('tasks'). to be clear whatever I name I pass in Celery() i.e. Celery('ion') the task should be run like celery worker -A ion -l info. I get no errors when I run it(I haven't tried shell yet), but when in my browser no calculations are taking place when I use add.delay(1,2) it just remains the same. thanks tho. You came the closest to helping me to my goal. You'll probably be responding to me again before the day is out.

Comment: It's good to hear you got it to run. Now if it isn't actually running the tasks you defined, first thing you need to do is to import your task in manage.py shell and run .delay() on it there, and check if celery shell gives you any information about it receiving the task.

Comment: I ran the shell from src and got No module named 'tasks' I then I cd'd into blog antried to import it like so from tasks import add and got the following message Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import.

Comment: Are you running "python manage.py shell" ? How is it possible to get that error since the tasks.py is already there in your blog module ? It's not possible since the blog is in your PYTHONPATH when you run python manage.py shell.
You should definitely be able to import it like: *from blog.tasks import X*

Comment: I shut everything down and now i'ts running in the background. But I still don't know how to make it work in the shell

Comment: I don't know what now your facing, but notice that if you shut down celery, its shut down ! It won't run in the background or something. To run in the background, you need a process manager, like supervisor or an init script. Normally, when you close it, it's closed and won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a long warning, telling you not to use *pickle* in case [you're not familiar with it's possible side effects](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#isn-t-using-pickle-a-security-concern). So it's better to set celery serializer to use json.

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Now to the main problem, the task that's being run is, as the error indicates, **blog.tasks.p_panties**, But as the output of running celery worker indicates, the task that's registered with celery, is **tasks.p_panties**.

The problem is arising since you're creating the celery app instance, inside your **tasks.py**, so it's registering tasks with names like **task.***.

The solution to this is to create a *celery.py* in your root directory and setup the celery app there and then finally, import that app object into your tasks.py file.

the contents of the celery.py would be like the following:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', DEFAULT_SETTINGS_MODULE
)

app = Celery('app_name')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and then in your tasks.py, import it like below:

```
from blog.celery import app
```

As can be seen, in the **celery.py** file, I've instantiated celery, and called `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')`. This way celery knows to read its configuration parameters from your django settings file. So all celery settings, would go there, including `BROKER_URL` and other settings (that you're passing directly to the celery object)

**Edit**

And don't run celery like : `celery worker -A tasks -l info`

run it like : `celery worker -A project_name -l info`

Comment: why do the tutorials seem to work for the people who write them? I'm following exactly what to do. 
And If it desn't work like that why do they write it like that?

Comment: Celery docs are indeed a little bit messy and misleading, more so when it comes to routing_keys and queues, and the difference between kombu queues and the amqp queues and so on. But it's an advanced tool, and getting used to the way it works, needs alittle time and effort.

Comment: ('django.conf:settings') also applies to this DEFAULT_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'gettingstarted.settings' which also in my settings file, or do I have to import settings and explicitly put , from gettingstarted.settings.local import DEFAULT_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: when I do what you suggested I get which is from blog.celery import app I get  No module named 'blog' if I try from .celery import app I get Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Comment: Can you add the full structure of your project in the question, I need to see where your manage.py and settings.py are.

Comment: I just updated it so you can see the directories. I have a settings directory with base, local and production. and Imanage.py is in my src directory

Comment: Looking at your directory structure, you should be okay running celery with:
**celery worker -A blog -l info**, initiate the command inside the src/ folder, (Where *ls* shows blog, gettingstarted and manage.py)

Comment: I get a no mudule named task. this is really crazy. every tutorial I've followed to a tee. but I know somehow it's my fault.

Comment: Please provide your celery.py, exactly how you run the celery worker, and in which directory you run so. You really don't have a *task* module, it's *tasks*.

Comment: I did it above. Check it out